# VMware tools crashing with root access in Ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: login, lightdm, vmware

I'm trying to enable graphical root login with commands on Ubuntu 14.04.2:

```
sudo passwd root
sudo sh -c 'echo "greeter-show-manual-login=true" >> /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf'
```

Portions of the VMware tools crash associated with lightdm

Is there any way to enable root access graphically at the login menu without conflicting with the VMware tools?

```
# ~/.profile: executed by Bourne-compatible login shells.
```

if [ "$BASH" ]; then
  if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
  fi
fi
mesg n

---

bashrc:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells. 
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
```

[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

```
# don't put duplicate lines in the history. See bash(1) for more options
# ... or force ignoredups and ignorespace
```

HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace

```
# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
```

shopt -s histappend

```
# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
```

HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

```
# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
```

shopt -s checkwinsize

```
# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
```

[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

```
# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
```

if [ -z "$debian_chroot" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

```
# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
```

case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

```
# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes
```

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}[\033[01;32m]\u@\h[\033[00m]:[\033[01;34m]\w[\033[00m]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

```
# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
```

case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

```
# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
```

if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

```
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
```

fi

```
# some more ls aliases
```

alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

```
# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.
```

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

```
# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
#if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
#    . /etc/bash_completion
#fi
```

Comment: Not recommended.

Comment: Changing configuration of lightdm requires reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute this command

`sudo gedit /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf`

Then add this statement

`greeter-show-manual-login=true`

Restart your machine and It should work.

Comment: I get the following error now though, I guess its related:                                      Error when found when loading /root/.profile: stdin: is not a tty

Comment: Can you copy paste contents of /root/.profile file in question, execute this command: "sudo gedit /root/.profile" then copy contents of file and paste it into your question.

Comment: And also try adding "pty=True" (without quotes) at the end of /root/.profile

Comment: adding "pty=True" yields the following in terminal:           (gedit:7308): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

Comment: hopefully you understand the edit in the question (formatting is different obviously)

Comment: Paste output of  /root/.bashrc in question

Comment: output is in the question

Comment: replace "mesg -n" by "tty -s && mesg n" and delete "pty=True" in /root/.profile , then logout and login again

Comment: Im getting the Same result :/

Comment: I suppose it is a bug, you should report it [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/)